# filter nested object Array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to filter a tree of directories and files (UNKOWN depth)

I'm getting a part of a file name from the client,

and I need to return the tree filtered by file name

I tried filtering like this

```
  var data = [
    {
        "name": "ng-web-mla-analytics",
        "files": [
            "tsconfig.app.json",
            "tsconfig.json",
            "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "tslint.json",
            "yarn.lock"
        ],
        "directories": [
            [
                {
                    "name": "src",
                    "files": [
                        "sql",
                        "template.html",
                        "test.ts"
                    ],
                    "directories": [
                        ,
                        [
                            {
                                "name": "store",
                                "files": [
                                    "app-state.model.ts",
                                    "TppA2.ts",
                                    "reducers.ts"
                                ],
                                "directories": [
                                    [
                                        {
                                            "name": "config",
                                            "files": [
                                                "config-state.model.ts",
                                                "config.actions.ts",
                                                "config.effects.ts",
                                                "config.reducer.ts",
                                                "config.service.spec.ts",
                                                "config.service.ts"
                                            ],
                                            "directories": []
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    [
                                        {
                                            "name": "filters",
                                            "files": [
                                                "filters-state.model.ts",
                                                "tppA1.actions.ts",
                                                "filters.effects.ts",
                                                "filters.reducer.ts",
                                                "filters.service.spec.ts",
                                                "filters.service.ts"
                                            ],
                                            "directories": []
                                        }
                                    ],
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            ];

function filterNestedArray2(arr, filtrString) {
    return arr.filter(item => {
      console.log("iten", item)
      if (Array.isArray(item.directories) && item.directories.length) {
        return filterNestedArray(item.directories, fileString);
                    }
      else if (Array.isArray(item.files)) {
        return item.files.filter(fileName => {
          return fileName.includes(filtrString)
                        })
                    }
                });
            }
  
  var filtered = filterNestedArray(data, 'auto.ts');
  
  console.log(filtered);
```

Expand snippet
any suggestions?

I looked up for some answers, but the didn't suit

let's say that the api gut an "TppA" for example, so the filterString should be it, and each branch that has files array to contains value that includes that, should return, e.g -
the results should be as flow:

```
var FilteredData = [
    {
        "name": "ng-web-mla-analytics",
        "files": [
            "tsconfig.app.json",
            "tsconfig.json",
            "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "tslint.json",
            "yarn.lock"
        ],
        "directories": [
            [
                {
                    "name": "src",
                    "files": [
                        "sql",
                        "template.html",
                        "test.ts"
                    ],
                    "directories": [
                        ,
                        [
                            {
                                "name": "store",
                                "files": [
                                    "TppA2.ts",
                                ],
                                "directories": [
                                    [
                                        {
                                            "name": "filters",
                                            "files": [
                                                "TppA1.actions.ts",
                                            ],
                                            "directories": []
                                        }
                                    ],
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            ];
```

and any branch that doesn't have this value throw his entire depth should not be presented

Comment: Can you add your input values and your expected output to your question, please? You could change your question to include a [mcve], and you can use the snippet tool `[<>]` in the question edit toolbar to help you.

Comment: can you give an example so, that i can understand in better way?

Comment: Where does callback come from?

Comment: I have converted your code into a snippet that can be run right here.  I had to just take a guess at how you are calling the function and what data you are passing into it though so please edit this if I took a wrong guess.  Please include things like this in future questions so that people do not have to guess when they are trying to help you.  It also appears you have an error in your code because the function named `filterNestedArray2` calls a function named `filterNestedArray` (without the `2`) which does not exist.

Comment: [Why you shouldn't use var any more](https://hackernoon.com/why-you-shouldnt-use-var-anymore-f109a58b9b70) (dated 2016).

Comment: i eddited it adding an example,  this function i wrote can be replaced with a better one